# How to get a collection of elements in my dictionary that meet a given condition?

Tags: vb.net, collections, attributes

I am going through some pluralsight videos and I found this amazing one called "Beautiful C++ 14: STL Alorithms". In this video the instructor discusses using the a variation of find_if methods like the one below.

---

```
vector<int> v{  4, 6, 6, 1, 3, -2, 0, 11, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4 };

//find the first zero in the collection
auto result = find(begin(v), end(v), 0);
```

---

These methods are fantastic and I will be using it for some of my C projects, but I am currently working in a VB project where I need some kind of the same functionality.

I have a dictionary and I need to get certain objects out of it based on an if statement.

---

```
Structure Example_Struct
    Public ExampleItem1 As Integer
    Public ExampleItem2 As Integer
End Structure

Private Example_Dictionary As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Example_Struct)

Private Sub PopulateDictionaryWithDummyData()
    Dim dummyData1 As Example_Struct
    Dim dummyData2 As Example_Struct

    dummyData1.ExampleItem1 = 1
    dummyData1.ExampleItem2 = 1

    dummyData1.ExampleItem1 = 5
    dummyData1.ExampleItem2 = 5

    Example_Dictionary.Add("Data1", dummyData1)
    Example_Dictionary.Add("Data2", dummyData2)

End Sub
Private Sub LoadData()

    PopulateDictionaryWithDummyData()

    Dim stIdx As Integer
    Dim myStruct As New Example_Struct
    Dim item1 As Integer = 5
    Dim item2 As Integer = 5
    Dim count As Integer = Example_Dictionary.Count

    For stIdx = 1 To count

        ' Get the stand data
        myStruct = Example_Dictionary.ElementAt(stIdx).Value

        If (myStruct.ExampleItem1 = item1 And myStruct.ExampleItem1 = item2) Then

            ' Do Something

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

---

Above is some sample code to test with were I populate my Example_Dictionary with some dummy data. Then loop through the dictionary and put the comment where I need to do some things.

I would like my code to take the for loop out of the picture completley, just grab the "Example_Struct" that matches my conditions.

If there are more than one "Example_Struct" that matches my condition, I would need it to return a collection of these.

Comment: Hey, the ''' Stand_INFO_Dictionary ''' is a dictionary that holds our stand's index and the stand structure, the stand structure is a MASSIVE structure full of loads of information. In this project we have over 300 stands. The edited question I provided above keeps it simple and reproducable and the intended functionallity described.

Comment: You can use something like `Dim myStructs = Example_Dictionary.Values.Where(Function(x) x.ExampleItem1 = item1 AndAlso x.ExampleItem2 = item2).ToList()`. Always use `AndAlso` instead of `And` and `OrElse` instead of `Or` when dealing with logical operations.

Comment: The .NET equivalents to the STL algorithms will typically be in Linq.  Whereas the STL uses separate begin and end iterators, Linq uses enumerators that have a built-in end concept (and the `For Each` loop is also built around this concept).

Answer (score 1):

To filter the dictionary *values* based on a certain condition, you may use something like the following:

```
Dim myStructs = Example_Dictionary.Values.
    Where(Function(x) x.ExampleItem1 = item1 AndAlso x.ExampleItem2 = item2).ToList()
```

Note that when dealing with logical operations, it's always a good idea to use the short-circuit logical operators (i.e., `AndAlso` instead of `And` and `OrElse` instead of `Or`). You can learn more about the difference in this guide:

[Logical and Bitwise Operators in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators)